# Intellij GitHub plugin unable to add reviewers

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2 Ultimate Edition.

I use the GitHub plugin bundled with it to create pull reviews. I am however not able to add reviewers when I create them.

Is this even possible? If not can the support folks please direct me if I can raise this request (or perhaps even contribute to this?)

Some UI to work with pull requests would be great too so it would be amazing to see if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85079 and related, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146659

You are welcome to contribute if you would like. See https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md